# How to use regex in active record queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

There are values in a specific column of my database that ends with a number but others that do not. 
I'm trying to only take the data that is not containing these numbers.

I tried to use these queries but they do not work :

```
User.where.not("spec like ?", "%\d")
User.where.not("spec ~ ?", "%\d")
```

How could I find this data ?

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: @MarekLipka I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: What about just `User.where.not("spec like '%[0-9]'")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't work either :( . It returns an error : PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RLIKE"

Comment: @Benjamin That would work if you used MySQL. I removed the comment. `User.where.not("spec SIMILAR TO ?", "%[0-9]")` will work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Still not working but no errors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yessss it works ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) with `%[0-9]` pattern:

```
User.where.not("spec SIMILAR TO ?", "%[0-9]")
```

The `SIMILAR TO` operator is similar to regex, but allows the use of wildcards as with `LIKE` and some "light" regex constructs, e.g.  bracket expressions like `[0-9]` or `[A-Z]`. The pattern should match the whole input as with `LIKE`.

So, the `%[0-9]` pattern will match any strings that start with any text (`%` wildcard does that) and end with an ASCII digit (due to the `[0-9]` at the end).